# Iterating through Google events that are in the past

Tags: algorithm, rest, paging, google-calendar-api

I'm implementing view for google events in my application using the following end-point:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

The problem that I have is implementing a feature to make it possible to go to the previous page of events. For example: user is having 20 events for the current date and once he presses the button, they have 20 past events. 
As I can see, Google provides only:

```
"nextPageToken": string
```

That fetches the results for the next page. 
The way I see the problem can be solved:

1. Fetch results in descending order and then traverse them the same way as we do with nextPageToken. The problem is that it is stated in the doc that only asc is available:

> "startTime": Order by the start date/time (ascending). This is only
>   available when querying single events (i.e. the parameter singleEvents
>   is True)

2. Fetch all the events for specific time period, traverse the pages until I get to the current date or to the end of the list, memorize all the nextPageTokens. Use memorized values to be able to go backwards. The clear drawback of it is the fact that we need to go through unpredictable number of pages to get the current date. That can dramatically affect the performance. But, at least it is something that Google APIs allow. Updated: Checked that approach with 5 years time span and sometimes it takes up to 20 seconds to get the current date page token.

Is there a more convenient way to implement the ability to go to the previous pages?

Comment: You may send [`Events: list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) request with optional parameter `pageToken` which specifies which result page to return. If that functionality doesn't help, you may file a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/support#missing_features).